# RDFS: if A hasManager B, can it be inferred that B manages A?

Tags: rdfs, inference, triplestore

I'm a bit confused as to what can be inferred from RDFS triples.

If there's a shop with a staff Lily and manager Dan,

and `shop:Lily shop:hasManager shop:Dan`

can it be inferred that `shop:Dan shop:manages shop:Lily`?

or are they technically speaking different relationships and hence cannot be inferred?

Answer (score 2):

The [OWL property `inverseOf`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-ref-20040210/#inverseOf-def) allows you to define an inverse relation between properties.

So it could be inferred (as [@JeenBroekstra notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286675/rdfs-if-a-hasmanager-b-can-it-be-inferred-that-b-manages-a/40294234?noredirect=1#comment67850370_40294234), only by an OWL reasoner) if you state something like:

```
shop:hasManager owl:inverseOf shop:manages .
```

Comment: Note that this is an **OWL** property though - so this will only be inferred by an OWL reasoner. If your triplestore only supports RDFS inferencing, this will not work.